Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<init>()
Trying to create a native image using GraalVM and Spring Boot. The app itself works when i use the mvn spring-boot:run command, but when I build my native image and try to run it, I get this exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': org.hibernate.bytecode.spi.BytecodeProvider: org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[app:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[app:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[app:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[app:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[app:3.2.4]
    at com.library.app.AppApplication.main(AppApplication.java:10) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.bytecode.spi.BytecodeProvider: org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:675) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1236) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1269) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderSpliterator.tryAdvance(ServiceLoader.java:1485) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:241) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator.initiateService(BytecodeProviderInitiator.java:50) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.BytecodeProviderInitiator.initiateService(BytecodeProviderInitiator.java:22) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[app:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[app:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[app:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:69) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:46) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.createSessionFactoryBuilder(DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.java:26) ~[app:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:170) ~[app:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[app:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[app:6.1.5]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<init>()
    at java.base@22/java.lang.Class.checkExecutable(DynamicHub.java:1101) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.lang.Class.checkConstructor(DynamicHub.java:1082) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1272) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2452) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:662) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659) ~[na:na]
    at java.base@22/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:113) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571) ~[app:na]
    at java.base@22/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:670) ~[app:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted




I've tried to mess with the pom file, use different plugins and dependencies, but of no avail.
The command I use to build the image is:
mvn -Pnative native:compile
This is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>GraalVM Student Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I'd be mildly surprised if an app that messes with bytecode can have a native image, but maybe Graal is smarter than I think?

@LouisWasserman Recent version Spring (Boot) can do the processing at compile-time using mvn spring-boot:process-aot mvn -Pnative native:compile or similar.

What Spring Boot version are you using? How exactly are you building the native image? Can you show your pom.xml?

@dan1stmightbehappyagain Thanks for the response, the pom.xml has been added to the question.

Still, how are you generating the native binary?

mvn -Pnative native:compile

That's the only one I use. This is really frustrating because when I clone someone else's Spring Boot project, it builds the binary just fine, but when I do it on my own project, I get only exceptions. Maybe it has something to do with my entity classes?

Or is there a mismatch between Hibernate and this Bytebuddy dependency?

It is strange that I encountered the error only after generating hints using the tracing agent. Before that, it was fine.

It seems to be related to the anonymous classes added in the BytecodeProviderImpl class. How should work reflection for anonymous class in native mode. Currently I can see that if canonical name is null, a validation error is raised ( see code from ReflectionTypeReference.java)

Was able to solve it myself, although not in the way I originally imagined.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39744
Apparently, there is an issue with Hibernate and it needs to be downgraded to at least 6.4.2 (the current version is 6.5.0.CR1) in the properties section of the POM.xml.

Could you put your pom.xml with the downgraded version?

I guess I found the issue. I decompiled the code for hibernate-core 6.4.4 that comes from Spring Boot 3.2.4 version.
Interestingly, I found out that BytecodeProviderImpl class present in it supports only JDK 11.
This is the constructor which checks for VM from JDK 11:
public BytecodeProviderImpl() {
   this(ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V11));
}

The fact that you are trying to execute the code using JDK 22 that I can see from logs.
That's why the code is unable to compile giving this absurd error.
I will suggest to check whether or not downgrading JDK 22 to 11 works for you.

@userM1433372 See if this helps you.
